# ForegroundService suddenly not emiting any notifications

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I've changed nothing in my code and suddenly my IntentService (started as ForegroundService) is not emitting any notification at all. It is still running, but I don't get any notification.

I tried changing the channel ID, looked the app up if android is blocking notifications, but nothing changed since last time.

From my Fragment where I start the Service:

```java
    public void startRefresh() {
        Intent fetchIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FetchService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            getActivity().startForegroundService(fetchIntent);
        } else {
            getActivity().startService(fetchIntent);
        }
    }
```

The service itself:

```java
public class FetchService extends IntentService {

    public static final String notificationChannelId = "DEFAULT_CHANNEL";


    public FetchService() {
        super("FetchService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannel();

        startForeground(1, getProgressNotification("fetching started"));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }

    private Notification getProgressNotification(String text) {

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_round_refresh_24px_blk)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fetching_new_data))
                .setContentText(text)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setProgress(0, 0, true).build();
    }


    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(FetchService.notificationChannelId, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description)

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that the foreground service is showing a notification as it usually does. At this point the service is running (`onHandleIntent() is called) and gets stopped properly. The notification instead isn't shown at all.

**EDIT:**
So after re-installing the app it seems to work again... Strange but I hope it continuous to work

Comment: The service is doing it's work properly. That is not the problem. The problem is, that the Service is not showing any notification while it is doing it's work, although it is started as ForegroundService.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you don't understand me. The service isn't stopped unless the work in `onHandleIntent()` is done. After that the service is stopped, yes. But the notification should be there. while the service is processing,